# What kind of data structure should I use to capture character attributes in a role playing game

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, maps

What kind of data structures should I use to capture characteristics such as strength, agility, charisma, etc for a Role Playing Game? I also want to assign personality types based on the kind of sub quests a player completes and a minimum level of attributes for various reputation types.

It's for a Java based Data Structures and Algorithms class I am taking. The game is going to be very small and simple. Should I just use arrays or would a map be better suited for this?

Example of data:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a fixed set of Attributes? I would suppose so. Just use a POJO

```
public class Attributes {
  int strength = 0; //or use a nice default
  int agility = 0;
  int charisma = 0;
  int intelligence = 0;
  int endurance = 0;
  int luck = 0;
}
```

Then generate getters and setters. You could then provide minimum sets with an instance of a class and implement a checkMinimum method based on this. Each Warrior would have his own instance.

I am afraid I don't understand your second requirement with the personality types.